# Not getting IPN response to listener in PayPal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I had created a created a recursive payment button in PayPal sandbox button . But while returning to test account from PayPal payment after payment, IPN response is not returning.While checking in the IPN history,it shows that the IPN message had generated.

ipn_POST_data is null in the listener.

The same is working for simple subscription button.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

we need to set the variable 'rm' as 2.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">

0 – all shopping cart payments use the GET method
1 – the buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but no payment variables are included
2 – the buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included
```

by default the value for rm will be 0.

thank you...